# How to efficiently read binary file in Scilab? Why doesn't readb work?

Tags: scilab

Scilab documentation for all versions shows that readb is the exact function I'm looking for but it is not recognized by the interpreter (I get Undefined variable: readb)

I'd love to use
pileofdata = readb(filename.bin, -1, 32) or even something that breaks up the data based on formatted input (ushort, ushort, long long, …) so I get arrays of my information right away.

I could use something to find the length of the binary file then use mgeti for the integers (and skip the floats), but this seems silly/inefficient.  This seems to defeat the point of using binary data.

any tips?  Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you use `mgeti`by itself ?

Comment: I can, but each line is a mixture of ushorts, longlong, float, etc.  I can use a loop and mget for each part
time=mget(1,'l',fileid);
data=mget(1,'us',fileid);
etc., but it takes about 10x longer than using csvRead for a similar dataset in ascii.

Comment: I can get rid of the floats on the data collection end, but am stuck with mixed ushorts and longlongs.  thanks.

Comment: Based on your 'mgeti' comment @Stephane, I revisited it with some success by reading all as uint16s, and clumsily combining four of those into a uint64.  There is probably a better way than how I converted four uint16's into one uint64 that I don't know of.  This is what I came up with.  I'm glad you asked the question as this is much faster

Comment: [fid, err] = mopen(fileandpath);
    
                x = mgeti(filebytes/2, 'us', fid); // opens all as uint16
                x = matrix(x,16,-1)'; // 16 columns, -1 to do all files (redim)
            mclose(fid);
            chan = x(:,2); // "chan" is a uint16
            timestamp = uint64(x(:,3)) .* 16^0 + uint64(x(:,4)) .* 16^4 + uint64(x(:,5)) .* 16^8 + uint64(x(:,6)) .* 16^16;
            energy = x(:,7); //"energy" is a uint16